# Which version of git is Xcode 5 running?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git

Just out of curiosity. I know that in the previous versions of Xcode (like Xcode 4), it was using its own (outdated) version of git. Is that still the case or is it using the one in current user's Path ?

Thanks.

Comment: `git --version` will tell you what you have...

Comment: @clive I have 1.9.0 installed via homebrew, Apple will keep using its own, right ?

Comment: @Wain Thanks but that's not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following from bash or a bash-like shell:

```
$(xcode-select -print-path)/usr/bin/git --version
```

From csh or tcsh, this will do the same thing:

```
`xcode-select -print-path`/usr/bin/git --version
```

This will show you the git version number for your currently-selected version of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to to just call "git --version" on Xcode 5's git.

For me, calling this from terminal did it:

```
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git --version
```

You might have to change the path if Xcode is installed somewhere else.

Comment: I accepted bdesham's because it was more flexible than yours, but thanks anyway!